# How to set the @font-face for a range of font-weights

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I want my @font-face to apply to a range, of, say, 0 to 400 font-weight values. It appears that my @font-face applies only to the explicit font-weight specified in it. For example:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   src: url('Roboto/Roboto-Bold.tff');
   font-weight: 200;
}
```

If I used:

```
span { font-weight: 201; font-family: 'Roboto';}
```

It doesn't apply.

Comment: try to remove the single quote

Comment: You must have amazing eye site to tell the difference between 200 and 201!

Comment: @sheriffderek It's mainly because I don't know what other designers might put for font-weight. I wanted the fonts to apply to as many valid values as possible. But I think the answer is there are only 9 valid font-weight values.

Comment: If the font doesn't have a font weight, you will be doing a disservice by defining one. Firefox will try and fake the weight and hurt the typeface. Same would go for italic, if there is no version of it for the font.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are only [9 valid font-weights](http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/).

Comment: Also, not every font has all of those weights available.

Answer (score 1):

Saw an article in MDN

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Manrope';
    font-display: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400 600;
    src: url('URL');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-weight

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the single quote :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Roboto;
   src: url(Roboto/Roboto-Bold.tff);
   font-weight: 200;
}

span { font-weight: 200; font-family: Roboto;}
```

Comment: font weight 201?

Comment: @sheriffderek Fool of me sorry about that.

Comment: quotes in background: url("...") and things like that are optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: Roboto;
src: url(../fonts/Roboto-Bold.eot);
src: url(../fonts/Roboto-Bold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
font-weight: 700;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial; font-weight: 100;}
```